# Can this divisor and floor function be calculated faster

Tags: combinatorics, divisor-sum, divisors-algebraic-geometry, divisor-counting-function

Let $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. Example: $d(6) = 4$ because $6$ has $4$ divisors {$1, 2, 3, 6$} (Sequence [A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005)).

Let $D(n)$ is the sum of first $n$ functions $d(x)$. Or we have $D(n) = \overset{n}{\underset{x=1}{\Large \Sigma}} d(x)$ (Sequence [A006218](https://oeis.org/A006218)).

It is known that $D(n) = \overset{n}{\underset{x=1}{\Large \Sigma}} \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor \normalsize = 2\overset{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}{\underset{x=1}{\Large \Sigma}} \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor \normalsize - {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}^2$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ **[1]**

It is also known that $S = \Large\{ \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{1} \Large \rfloor \normalsize, \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{2} \Large \rfloor \normalsize, \dots, \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{n - 1} \Large \rfloor \normalsize, \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{n} \Large \rfloor \normalsize \Large \Large \}$ have $O(\sqrt{n})$ unique numbers or/and $|S| \leq 2\sqrt{n} + 1$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ **[2]**

Using **[1]** or **[2]** the function $D(n)$ can be calculated in $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Furthurmore, we can also calculate $D(n)$ in $O(\sqrt[3]{n})$ using the algorithm Richard Sladkey described in the paper [A Successive Approximation Algorithm for Computing the Divisor Summatory Function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3369) $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ **[3]**

---

---

---

Let $s(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$. Example: $d(6) = 4$ because $6$ has $4$ divisors {$1, 2, 3, 6$} (Sequence [A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203)).

Let $S(n)$ is the sum of first $n$ functions $s(x)$. Or we have $S(n) = \overset{n}{\underset{x=1}{\Large \Sigma}} d(x)$ (Sequence [A024916](https://oeis.org/A024916)).

It is known that $S(n) = \overset{n}{\underset{x=1}{\Large \Sigma}} \overset{\Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor}{\underset{k=1}{\Large \Sigma}} k = \overset{n}{\underset{x=1}{\Large \Sigma}} \Large ( \normalsize x \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor \Large ) \normalsize$

My question-1: Is there a simple $O(\sqrt{n})$ sigma formula other than using the lemma **[2]**

My question-2: But can it be calculated in $O(\sqrt[3]{n})$. Since this [table](https://oeis.org/A072692/b072692.txt) calculated for $n = 10^{36}$

---

---

---

Let $T(n) = \overset{n}{\underset{x=1}{\Large \Sigma}} \Large ( \normalsize d(x) \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor \Large ) \normalsize$ (Sequence [A061201](https://oeis.org/A061201)).

My question-3: Is there a simple $O(\sqrt{n})$ sigma formula or how can I use the lemma **[2]** to calculate in $O(\sqrt{n})$

My question-4: Can it be calculated faster than $O(\sqrt{n})$. Since this [table](https://oeis.org/A180365/b180365.txt) calculated for $n = 10^{23}$